# ThinkorSwim Linux install with 4k Display

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install thinkorswim on my POP 20.04 system.  I have a 4k display which is rendering the installer to be small, unsizable, and unable to scroll through the options to move onto the next step of the installation.

```
bash ./thinkorswim_installer.sh
```

perhaps there is a way to launch it via the terminal with different size settings?

[image: lookie here]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244711/thinkorswim-installer-too-small

Changed the display scaling to 100% then ran the installer.